# How to remote desktop from Windows XP into Windows VISTA?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, rdesktop

How can I remote desktop from Windows XP into Windows Vista premium edition?

Answer (score 1):

start->run->**mstsc.exe**

Note that you need to know the username/password to a local administrator account on the Vista machine, or otherwise explicitly enable an account for remote-desktop usage by right-clicking *My Computer*->properties->remote->remote users.

Comment: You also need a Vista edition that supports Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Before any remote desktop connections are going to happen from xp to vista, on the vista machine you must go to control panel->system->advanced system settings->remote and check the box that says, "Allow connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop (less secure)".

Click apply and restart the vista machine.

Once you are back into windows make sure that there is a password set on the user you wish to access remotely as vista cannot accept connections without credentials.

Short of that just go register for a free account on [logmein](https://secure.logmein.com/US/home.aspx)  add the vista box into your account as a connectable machine and install the client software.  After that remoting into it is a breeze just log in from the xp box and click connect on the vista machine.

Comment: Vista Home Premium does not have Remote Desktop support, you cannot enable it from the "Remote" tab, only remote assistance connections.

Answer (score 0):

If your Vista machine has given this access to the credentials you are using, you can run mstsc.exe from the command line and enter the Vista machine's name or IP address.

Comment: You also need a Vista edition that supports Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Vista Home Premium does not support Remote Desktop. Your best bet would be to use remote control software (RealVNC, UltraVNC, TightVNC) or remote support software like GoToMyPC Free.